# Kubernetes master fails to connect every few seconds - strange error (Debian 11 OS)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, debian, ufw

```
inst@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
calico-kube-controllers-674fff74c8-g9dkn   1/1     Running            1 (31s ago)      64s
calico-node-9rpjc                          0/1     Running            0                64s
calico-node-gfwsb                          0/1     Running            0                64s
calico-node-rp584                          0/1     Running            0                64s
coredns-5d78c9869d-dhft7                   1/1     Running            2 (25s ago)      19m
coredns-5d78c9869d-ggjb4                   1/1     Running            2 (25s ago)      19m
etcd-k8s-master                            1/1     Running            10 (5m52s ago)   18m
kube-apiserver-k8s-master                  1/1     Running            11 (5m23s ago)   19m
kube-controller-manager-k8s-master         1/1     Running            16 (3m21s ago)   18m
kube-proxy-btm5h                           0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (40s ago)      15m
kube-proxy-clm69                           1/1     Running            2 (32s ago)      2m1s
kube-proxy-mnv87                           1/1     Running            15 (102s ago)    19m
kube-scheduler-k8s-master                  1/1     Running            13 (91s ago)     18m
inst@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
The connection to the server 192.168.0.211:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

There are about 5-10 seconds between these two commands

So far I have tried restarting the server, reloading the Linux firewall and deleting and re-entering the ports on the firewall.
I have also set a DNS entry on my PiHole
but unfortunately all this did not help.

I hope that the situation of the cluster will stabilize.

The cluster was initialized with Kubeadm.

The Pod-Network (should work) works with Calico.

Linux firewall is UFW installed on every Node.

```
inst@k8s-master:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10250/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
30000:32767/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere                  
6443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2379/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2380/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10251/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10252/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10255/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
179/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
4789/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51821/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
10250/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
30000:32767/tcp (v6)       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
6443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2379/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2380/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
10251/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
10252/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
10255/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
179/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
4789/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
51821/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

when i restart kubelet it works temporarily

```
inst@k8s-master:~$ sudo systemctl restart kubelet
inst@k8s-master:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
k8s-master    Ready    control-plane   50m   v1.27.1
k8s-worker1   Ready    <none>          45m   v1.27.1
k8s-worker2   Ready    <none>          32m   v1.27.1
```

Comment: You can go through this [public documentation](https://medium.com/@texasdave2/troubleshoot-kubectl-connection-refused-6f5445a396ed) which can help you solve the issue.